# Illegal parameter number in definiton of beamer frame Pandoc RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

While I want to render my Rmarkdown file as beamer pdf with Latex. I get the error:

> !Illegal parameter number in definiton
> of \beamer@doifinframe

I get this only within the columns Tag.

---

````
title: ""
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    toc: false
    keep_tex: false
params:
        one_touch_plot: NA
classoption: "aspectratio=169"   
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(markdown)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,
                      warning = FALSE,
                      message = FALSE)


```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{columns}[T]
      \begin{column}{0.27\textwidth}
```{r, out.width='100%', out.height='38%'}
params$one_touch_plot
``` 
    \end{column}
    \hfill
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
````

Answer (score 1):

Markdown has its own syntax for columns:

````
---
title: ""
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    toc: false
    keep_tex: false
params:
        one_touch_plot: NA
classoption: "aspectratio=169"  
---

# Section 1

## A vs B

::: columns

:::: column
```{r, out.width='100%', out.height='38%'}
params$one_touch_plot
``` 
::::

:::: column
other test
::::

:::
````

[image]